# less toggle raw-ness while viewing output

Tags: colors, less

I instinctively type `less -R <file>` whenever I want to view a file that might contain ansi escape codes (particularly for color).

Sometimes if I'm using less in a long pipeline though I forget the `-R` and can't easily go back and fix it without running the command again.

Do any of the common varieties of `less` (GNU or otherwise) expose the ability to switch between "raw" character mode and non-raw while the program is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command inside `less` is `-R`. Yes, exactly like the option on the command line.

> `-`      Followed by one of the command line option letters, this will change the setting of that option and print a message describing the new setting.  If  a ^P  (CONTROL-P)  is entered immediately after the dash, the setting of the option is changed but no message is printed.  If
>   the option letter has a numeric value (such as
>                 -b or -h), or a string value (such as -P or -t), a new value may be entered after the option letter.  If no new value is
>   entered, a message describing the current setting
>                 is printed and nothing is changed.

So by repeating `-R` you will toggle displaying control characters (you may need to hit enter after each command).

For long format options you have `--` and `-+`/`--+` resets short/long options to their default values. There are more similar commands: [man less](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html) is your friend.